# Use JQUERY to change a field's value for a pop up window. Change window size

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I want to change the "width" field from '600' to get '1000' or '100%'.

below is the html related to the content I want to change:

```
<a class="ButtonItem" onfocus="if (event &amp;&amp; event.altKey) { this.blur();
click(); this.blur();  }" accesskey="N" onclick="OppItemWin=window.open('/CPP/ePare.dll/Do? 
SID=169713643747575&amp;Act=273&amp;Mode=1&amp;CLk=T&amp;Key-
1=1&amp;Key0=7&amp;Key1=166322&amp;Key7=125','OPPORTUNITYITEM','width=600,height=180,
scrollbars=no,resizable=yes');" href="#"><font style="text-decoration:underline">N</font>ew</a>
```

Here's what I'm using :

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#???magical selector????').text('width', '1000px');

});
</script>
```

Okay, with help from a friend I've found how to do this. Instead of modifying the attributes for opening the window, I've added code on the actual pop up window itself:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
window.resizeTo(1000,300);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use an IDE that provides syntax highlighting and be sure to format your code in a legible manner. It will help to make issues like the missing apostrophe in your JavaScript stand out.

Comment: Thanks, on an rdp that won't copy/paste between machines and was hand typing.

Comment: does your `a` element actually have an `id`?

Comment: I do not know. I pasted in the html that includes what I want to select, but I have no idea how to select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **[css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**() . in jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#OpportunityItem').css('width', '1000px');

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it makes no changes. I'm sure it's a problem trying to select the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#OpportunityItem').attr('width', '1000px');

});

this should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To set the width of the element via jQuery,you can use [**width()**](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width-value) function:

```
$('#OpportunityItem').width("1000px");
```

Or

```
$('#OpportunityItem').width("100%");
```

Or pass the interger value

```
$('#OpportunityItem').width(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Still can't select the correct part of the dom to edit though.

Comment: Yes,that's the problem,you are not able to catch the correct element to apply the width.
Once you get the element with id 'OpportunityItem',you'll be able to set width.